# Spring based SOA using multiple WAR on Tomcat, what is the best way to enfore URL mapping?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am in the process of migrating an old model 1 java based website, to use an under development restful-api (with the long term goal of providing a *PaaS* and any other buzzwords I can find).

I want to use multiple different WAR files for different modules of functionality. I know how to do this

```
www.myLegacy.com/myWarFile/myFirstMethod
www.myLegacy.com/myWarFile/mySecondMethod
www.myLegacy.com/mySecondWarFile/ThirdMethod (in different war file, and consequently diff url)
```

However I want to be able to deploy multiple war files to the same url like :

```
www.myLegacy.com/myRest/myFirstMethod
www.myLegacy.com/myRest/mySecondMethod
www.myLegacy.com/myRest/ThirdMethod (this is in different war file to other methods)
```

This is would use the full spring stack (inc spring-mvc) with tomcat.

Any pointers please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible straight away as Tomcat starts different war files in different context paths.  Only thing I can think of is deploying myRest.war and mySecondWarFile.war and adding a mapping for `/ThirdMethod` in myRest application itself and routing the request to `/mySecondWar/ThirdMethod` .

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Apache httpd, nginx or the like, and route URLs accordingly.