# Handling multi-war setup with shared parent spring context in tomcat with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven

This may be a very rudimentary question, but please help me out if this is well-known and has been solved elsewhere.

I have a multi-war setup (all maven modules) say `kilo-webapp1` and `kilo-webapp2` as two WARs that I need to deploy on a Tomcat instance. These two webapps both use services from a common service jar, say `kilo-common-services.jar`. The `kilo-common-services.jar` has its own spring context that is loaded by the users of the jar viz. `kilo-webapp1` and `kilo-webapp2` in this case. It so happens that the initialization of the services in kilo-common-services takes a long time and hence I want it to happen only once (to ensure that the time it takes to bring up the instance is not very high) which also helps me to use it as a second level cache that it kept current in the JVM instance. To do this, we resorted to the following steps:

1. Modify the catalina.properties of CATALINA_BASE in tomcat to have `shared.loader` as `${catalina.base}/shared/lib`
2. Copied the `kilo-common-services.jar` and all of its dependent jars to the `CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib`. [Manual step]
3. Copy spring related jars to the `CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib` location [Manual step]
4. Created a `beanRefContext.xml` file in `kilo-common-services.jar`. Define a new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` here, where the constructor was provided with the location to the spring context file for the common services.
5. Noted the dependency scope of `kilo-common-services.jar` and every other dependency (like Spring related jars) as `provided` in the `kilo-webapp1` and `kilo-webapp2` pom files. For Spring this is needed to ensure that the classpath scanning actions are not triggered twice. Also this causes different `ClassCastException`s (for log4j lets's say) if not excluded via the `provided` scope.
6. web.xml for `kilo-webapp1` and `kilo-webapp2` indicated that the parentContext for them is the `servicesContext` defined in `kilo-common-services.jar`.

I was able to verify that only one instance of the services of kilo-common-services exist, but the setup as you might have imagined is painful. If someone has best practices about such a setup in an IDE like Eclipse, would really appreciate it. My problems are as below:

- #2 is becoming a challenge. I am currently running `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` on  `kilo-common-services` to copy dependent jars from `target/dependency` to the `shared/lib`  which is a woefully manual step. Time and again, I forget to regenerate dependencies and have to do a redeploy again.
- #3 is also not straight-forward as time and again there are newer common dependencies and we always have to remember to copy it to shared lib to avoid ClassCastExceptions
- #5 is again a maintenance nightmare.

Also as time progresses, there will more such disparate common jars that need to be shared and it would involve pain for each of those jars. Feel free to critique the setup and propose a better one in its place that may be easy to use (from an IDE as well). Would be happy to provide any other details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind are those services in **kilo-common-services.jar**? Web-Services ? Or just kind of library functionality which will be used as common code?

Comment: Regular library in-process services.

Comment: If it is just a common code library i would suggest to simply package it with both war files and your got rid of the separate deployment step (shared library) which usually causes problem in real life.

Comment: I think he wants to keep a cache on the app, that's why he wants only one instance of kilo-common. You could use a distributed cache, but that's adding a LOT of complexity :S.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am intrigued to know what these real life problems are, as I was under the impression this was exactly the problem maven, unit testing and continous integration were designed to solve ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your architecture is broken (and that's why you're struggling with the solution). You have two solutions:

1) If you want to share a service that *takes a long time (to initialise)* between two war applications, make that a separate service completely and access it via rest or any kind of remoting.

2) Merge both webapps into one.

Having the common library is the shared lib folder is going to bring you lots of headaches, and you'll end up rolling it back.

My (personal) approach would be to merge both applications, but keep the packages separate enough and have separate spring configurations. In this way, at least you still keep the logic separation of both webapps. 
Also since both run on the same container, there's little gain from having 2 separate wars (unless you're planning to move them to different containers very soon).

---

About the IDE, you can use the maven-cargo-plugin to start up a tomcat with several web applications with (almost) any configuration you want.

Comment: "Having the common library is the shared lib folder is going to bring you lots of headaches" Why ? You have one version of required files/classes in a shared location, whats the problem ... ? If you convert to REST calls thats a third web app you have to manage (and firstly develop the restful interface for)

Comment: The answer is in the original question: he wants to initialise the common services only once. The problem is very simple (but not obvious), it's very easy to create a classloader nightmare. This approach works fine with standard resources (e.g. jdbc connections) but having a full business logic stack in the shared  library is not. It also has the problem of how to inject the shared objects into both web applications (but this can be done with some jndi hackery)

Comment: "how to inject the shared objects into both web applications" Why would that be a problem ? you just do it as normal (in my case, include the jar as depdencies and inject with annotation. I still don't understand why its a "classloader nightmare". I have just moved all my jars to the shared folder and I had to increase MaxPermspace ... but my deployable war files have shrunk in size from 20mb to 400kb.

Comment: "This approach works fine with standard resources (e.g. jdbc connections)"
You clearly meant JDBC datasources (not connections). Well, that's a good example of shared business service - pooled JDBC datasources were always shared, and it was working fine. And they're not in any way "standard resources", they're common but not standard. So it's not clear why other business services can not be used in same way as JDBC datasources.
As for RESTifying them - this is a great performance impact. Now instad of calling a method in JVM you have to serialize your parameters in JSON, and same for response.

Answer (score 0):

We are developing restful soa, with spring and tomcat and utilizing Domain Driven Design (well thats the plan anyway). There is  migrationProject and a initial basic search service. Two separate WAR files, with two separate POMs.  Both utilize the same Domain objects.

So I will have separate project that will be just the DomainObjects I will wrap them up into a jar, and then using maven and/or jenkins it will deploy automatically (whenever I configure (for example when pushed to a specific repository).

Having two copies of the same jar, sounds like a much worse idea to me. Its not your architecture that is broken, its your deployment and development process thats needs improvement, imho.

([my kind of related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13688555/106261)).

Our long term plan is to have one project as the restful interface, with multiple Controllers that have service classes and repositories injected into them from their dependencies.